# Image is not displaying in server - using PHP file upload

Tags: php, upload

I have a web site in php. Here I have uploaded image with size 1 MB. It's uploaded in the server successfully. But it's not displaying. I have enabled the read write permission to the folder, which contains images. While uploading smaller size it's working fine.

But in the case of larger image (greater than 1 MB) it's not working. I have checked my php info. There the file upload maximum size is 25 MB. So what could be the problem here?

Comment: Basic debugging first. What does the image's source look like when it's not displaying? I'll bet a beer it contains a "memory limit exhausted" error message. For help on that, see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735081/php-memory-limit-25mb-exhausted-file-upload-crop-resize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cases why this might happen:

1-Some web hosts include header or footer code when the output being served is **greater than a certain limit**. They usually use this for analytic purposes. See if you can remove these headers/footers or, if you are using readfile() from php, give a direct link to the browser instead.

2-Check the file size of the uploaded image, sometimes the upload gets cut off and no error message is given.

Also, an example link would have helped

Comment: My file uploaded in the server. But not displaying. I have checked the file property of that uploaded image. there the read permission is not checked. I have already  given the 777 permission to the folder which contains the images.It's only in the case of larger image (greater than 1 Mb ). Does any one help me ...

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at http://dk.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size please make sure the value of more than 1mb :)